# Floating certain tabs in Kendo tabstrip to the right issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

So I have 5 of my 11 tabs floated to the right, while the rest stay on the left of the screen as per the default layout of the kendo tabstrip. However, the last two tabs from the ones on the left of the screen can grow in size. They correctly fill up the white space between my left and right tabs until they reach my right tabs and begin pushing them off of the screen.

My issue is, when the right hand tabs are pushed off the screen, the kendo tabstrip scroll bars do not show up. They only show up when the left tabs get too long and go off of the screen. Then, when you scroll, you can only scroll to the end of the left hand tabs.

This dojo kind of displays the issue, except the right hand tabs just wrap around below tab 4. And it seems like the right hand tabs are simply being ignored altogether.

https://dojo.telerik.com/IHAqAP/2

Any help on this would be great!

Comment: what is currently image and what you want image, if provided can help to understand the problem more better

Comment: The dojo basically shows it. I found out that it was pushing my right hand tabs to a new line in the tabstrip instead of off the page, then only shows navigation when the left hand strips go off the page. I want the right hand tabs to get moved off the page when the left hand tabs grow and touch them and keep growing with navigation, instead of them falling to new line.